# How to remove the need for a namespace prefix?

Tags: c#, namespaces

I've written a class...

```
namespace SharpQuery
{
    public static class SharpQuery
    {
        public static IEnumerable<HtmlNode> Load(Uri uri)
        {
            // ...
```

But when I want to call the `Load` method from inside a different namespace I have to write `SharpQuery.SharpQuery.Load` even if I put `using SharpQuery;` at the top. Why is that? How do I get rid of the need to specify the namespace?

Comment: Does it really not compile or are you just trusting Intellisense? ;)

Comment: @Frederic: I was trusting Intellisense..... let me try it.

Comment: Nope. Doesn't compile either. `The type or namespace name 'Load' does not exist in the namespace 'SharpQuery' (are you missing an assembly reference?)`

Comment: Hmmm... `Load()` returns `IEnumerable<HtmlNode>` and the error mentions a "type or namespace", not a function call... Are you calling this as part of a LINQ expression? Can you provide the code that calls `Load()`?

Comment: @Frederic: Which makes sense, because it thinks `SharpQuery` is referring to the `namespace SharpQuery`, not the `class SharpQuery`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Eric Lippert wrote a series of blog posts saying that you shouldn't have namespaces and classes with the same names. Links here: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/tags/namespaces

He explains it much better than I could.

Comment: Yeesh.. 4 blog posts on one little topic? Maybe I'll read through those later, but for the time being, renaming the namespace does indeed fix the problem :) Thanks!

Comment: @Mark: I apologize for answering your question at such length. I didn't have the time to write something shorter.

Comment: @Eric: Haha.. no need to apologize! I appreciate you taking the time to write those articles for us n00bs :)

Comment: I wish @Eric had written this answer himself, just so I could +1 it for the Mark Twain quote.

Comment: @Jon: What Mark Twain quote? If you mean my loose translation of *"n'ai fait celle-ci plus longue parceque je n'ai pas eu le loisir de la faire plus courte"* above, that was Blaise Pascal in 1656, not Mark Twain.

Comment: @Eric, yes of course it was. On the plus side, I shall pretend to myself that I have a finite source of mistakes in a day, and since this one can't cause an app to crash, I shall delude myself that it's a win.

Comment: @Eric: I didn't know you knew French. Nice skills.

Comment: @Joan: I am Canadian, so I had five years of French in school. I can read and understand simple French if spoken slowly but I am pretty out of practice.

Comment: @Eric: I am very glad to hear this. I also live in Canada but not Canadian, but hopefully will get the citizenship early next year :O Are you from Vancouver? We should meet one day if you want.

Comment: @Joan: I am from Waterloo, which is near Toronto.

Comment: @Eric: I bet you went to U of W then? I heard it's the best in CompSci. Now I can attest to that :O

Comment: @Joan: I did go to UW; I have a B.Math in computer science and applied mathematics. And yes, UW has an excellent CS program.

Comment: @Eric: Thanks for the info. I admire that you have studied math in uni. I always think math is useful in many things especially with 3d stuff that I am working on at work, but by no means I am knowledgeable about it. At least I learn something new every day :O